# how to make sure that all Y axes on subplots have the same value

Tags: matlab

Here is the problem I am facing. I have the code, which builds some bar plots.

In order to compare them better, I need all them have the same scale. Looking at doc bar, I was not able to find how to specify that a bar plot has a specific maximum height.

So in my case, for example I have the following code:

```
c = [0 0 12 8 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0];
e = [0 2 5 6 5 2 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0];
f = [0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 19];
b = [0 9 7 0 0 1 0 1 0 1 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0];

subplot(2,2,1)
bar(b)
subplot(2,2,2)
bar(e)
subplot(2,2,3)
bar(f)
subplot(2,2,4)
bar(c)
```

The first subplot has height of 10, than 6, than 20 than 15.

Is there an easy way to have all of them their maximum height as 20.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use the [`linkaxes`](http://www.mathworks.de/de/help/matlab/ref/linkaxes.html) command:

```
h(1) = subplot(2,2,1)
bar(b)
h(2) = subplot(2,2,2)
bar(e)
h(3) = subplot(2,2,3)
bar(f)
h(4) = subplot(2,2,4)
bar(c)

linkaxes(h)
ylim([0 20])
```

Answer (score 5):

You can easily change axes properties using the `set` command and the handles (=identifiers) of the axes. If you haven't stored the axes handles (first output of `subplot`), you first have to find them:

```
%# collect axes handles
axH = findall(gcf,'type','axes');

%# set the y-limits of all axes (see axes properties for 
%# more customization possibilities)
set(axH,'ylim',[0 20])
```

Comment: How do you know which axis belongs to which plot? I can't seem to work out the ordering returned by `findall`